# Autoclose='outside' doesn't work with multiple menu in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a *dropdown* with 2 possibles menus that can reach each others by clicking on some dropdown items. By adding *autoClose='outside'* I fixed the problem of untimely closing when clicking somewhere in the dropdown main menu. But since I have another menu, once it's showed, the first time I open it, the *autoClose* doesn't really work, instead, it's as if it was never set, close the whole dropdown, and when I reopen it, go in the secondary menu for the second, this 'bug' doesn't occur again on this menu, but occurs when I go back in the first one etc..

I suspect it's because autoClose only works on the current selected menu, in the example below it works with the *main* menu and does not in the *secondary* menu first then, as described above, when I reopen the dropdown it shows directly the *secondary* menu, works, and once I go back in the *main* menu, it doesn't.

This is basically the code I'm running.

```
import {Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {useState} from 'react';

const Mydropdown = (props) => {

    const [menu,setMenu] = useState('main');

    return(
    <>
        <Dropdown autoClose='outside'>
        {
          menu=="main"
          &&
          (
            <>
              <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>setMenu("secondary")}>
                    Secondary menu
                </Dropdown.Item>
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </>
          )
        }
        {
          menu=="secondary"
          &&
          (
            <>
              <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>setMenu("main")}>
                    Secondary menu
                </Dropdown.Item>
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </>
          )
        }
      </Dropdown>
    </>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm following your requirements 100%, but this version should allow a single dropdown to optionally toggle contents (without auto-closing):

```
const Mydropdown = (props) => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState("main");

  return (
<Dropdown autoClose="outside">
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="primary">Dropdown Test</Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>        
    {menu == "main" && (
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setMenu("secondary")}>
        Secondary menu
      </Dropdown.Item>
    )}
    {menu == "secondary" && (
      <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setMenu("main")}>
        Main menu
      </Dropdown.Item>
    )}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
  );
};
```

Working example available here: https://codepen.io/ablewhite/pen/BawdVpg

Comment: Indeed, I found logic to split my menu with the Dropdown.Menu component, but just changing the items inside instead of the whole Menu component made it work. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want a dropdown menu with another dropdown menu inside of it? The following code would acomplish that, I would suggest using autoClose={false) to prevent the menu from closing.

import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useState } from "react"

const Mydropdown = (props) => {

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState("main")

return (
    <Dropdown autoClose={false}>

        <Dropdown.Toggle>
            Main Menu
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>

            <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setMenu("secondary")}>Action 1</Dropdown.Item>

            {menu === "secondary" &&
                <Dropdown autoClose={false}>

                    <Dropdown.Toggle>
                        Secondary
                    </Dropdown.Toggle>

                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setMenu("main")}>Action 2</Dropdown.Item>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>

                </Dropdown>
            }

        </Dropdown.Menu>

    </Dropdown>
)
```

}

export default Mydropdown